# Insert statement leaving column blank and causing errors

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to implement a basic user registration system using PHP. When I have a blank users table, I am able to register one user. Once registered, the password field is stored correctly as a hash but the column for the username is blank in the SQL table. After this insert, I am unable to insert any more rows (even with completely different username and passwords) until I delete the existing single row.

I have already tried removing all my validation so I have less code to troubleshoot for now until I can figure out what is going on.

Here is my function for performing the insert.

```
        function registerUser($username, $password) {
            $db = $this->getDbConnection();
                if (!is_null($db)) {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
                    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query)){
                    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);

                    // Set parameters
                    $param_username = $username;
                    $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

                    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
                        // Redirect to login page
                        header("location: /index.php");
                        exit();
                    } else {
                        echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                    }                

                    }
                // Close statement
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            }
            mysqli_close($db);
        }
```

This is how I created the users table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

And finally, this is my HTML form:

```
<div class="vertical-center">
    <div class="container roundedEdges mainContent divPadding10">
        <h2 class="textCenter">Sign Up</h2>
        <br>

      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
          <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
              <label>Username</label>
              <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
          </div>    
          <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
              <label>Confirm Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
              <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
              <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Reset">
          </div>
          <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
      </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

The id, password, and created_at fields are updated just fine, but the username is the problem.

EDIT: My function is inside a QueryRunner class. I'm calling it from a different file like so:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/DAL/queries.php');
$queryRunner = new QueryRunner;
$queryRunner->registerUser($username, $password);
```

Comment: Dump your parameters. What do they show? Where is your register function called?

Comment: For sure, your params are blank. So the user insert with empty value (your password too, but you are hasing it so it gets a new value. The second time you try, as you allready have a blank user it gives you an error (it's a unique column)

Comment: And as @Script47 says, you never call the function

Comment: ...in the code that we can see.

Comment: I just edited my post to show where the function is called. I wasn't able to use var_dump to get info about my parameters, but I'm not really familiar with that process.

Comment: It looks like my $username variable isn't being set, but I'm not sure why. I can only assume that the problem is with my HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that I have found the error here. I had commented out the code I was using to validate inputs because I thought the problem was elsewhere, but I guess I should have been paying closer attention to my validation logic. I had intended to read values from the POST array, validate them, and then handle to assignment to $username and $password variables right there in the validation functions.

It was this final step that I forgot.

Answer (score -1):

username filed is unique so every time before inserting into database make sure to check weather the data with the requested username exist or not and then perform insert query.

Comment: The point of this question is asking *why* the field is showing as empty.

Comment: maybe  while passing user name to your function it is set to null. try echo user username before passing it to function